# How can I delete value in the array by a condition on the php?

Tags: php, arrays, key

My first array like this :

```
$photoList = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'mu.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'city.jpg'
    )
);
```

My second array like this :

```
$photo = array('cover1'=>'chelsea.jpg', 'cover2'=>'arsenal.jpg');
```

If value of the second array is not inside the first array, it will remove the value from the second array

Based on the above example, because `arsenal.jpg` is not inside in the first array then it will deleted

So I want the new array from `$photo` is like this :

```
$photo = array('cover1'=>'chelsea.jpg');
```

I give another example. For example my `$photo` array like this :

```
$photo = array('cover1'=>'madrid.jpg', 'cover2'=>'barcelona.jpg');
```

Then the new array to be like this :

```
$photo = NULL
```

Because it's not inside `$photoList` array

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) to reduce the data, based on the [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) of `$photoList`:

```
$photo = array_filter($photo, function($item) use ($photoList) {
   return in_array($item, array_column($photoList, 'name')) ;
});

if (empty($photo)) $photo=null; // to transform empty array to null.

var_dump($photo);
```

Outputs :

```
array(1) {
  ["cover1"]=>
  string(11) "chelsea.jpg"
}
```

Or `NULL` for the second example.

Note that you also could extract `array_column` from the anonymous function, and pass it with `use()` :

```
$col = array_column($photoList, 'name') ;
$photo = array_filter($photo, function($item) use ($col) {
   return in_array($item, $col) ;
});
```

---

**Edit** to reindex keys :

```
$idx = 1 ;
foreach ($photo as $k => $v) {
    unset($photo[$k]);
    $photo['cover'.$idx++]=$v;
}
```

Comment: I want to ask. Can I update the key too. For example like this : `$photoList` array same with my question. But the `photo` array like this : `$photo = array('cover1'=>'liverpool.jpg', 'cover2'=>'city.jpg');`. From your code, the result is : `Array
(
    [cover2] => city.jpg
)`. I want the result : `Array
(
    [cover1] => city.jpg
)`. So it update the key to be `cover1` if there is not `cover1` key

Comment: @SuccessMan No, not using `array_filter`. I've updated the answer to reindex the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the Php functions: `array_intersect` and `array_column`:

```
$photo = array_intersect($photo, array_column($photoList, 'name')) ?: null;
```

Comment: I want to delete value of `$photo` array. Not `$photoList` array. Try to see my question again

Comment: Just fixed, sorry missed it

Comment: Try my code it exactly do what you need! @Success Man

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
<?php
$photoList = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'chelsea.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'mu.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'city.jpg'
    )
);
$photo = array('cover1'=>'chelsea.jpg', 'cover2'=>'arsenal.jpg');
foreach ($photo as $key => $value)// loop in $photo array
{
    if(!in_array( $value ,array_column($photoList, 'name')))//check if $photoList array has $value in column 'name'
    {
        unset($photo[$key]);//unset element
    }
}
print_r($photo);
?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [cover1] => chelsea.jpg )
```

**update :** code optimised by Progrock

```
$photoListNames = array_column($photoList, 'name');
foreach($photo as $key => $value)
    if(!in_array($value, $photoListNames))
        unset($photo[$key]);
```

Comment: You can slightly optimise this by taking your array_column call outside the foreach.  https://3v4l.org/nbCER